# SQL Detecting if only integers in varchar

Tags: sql

I'm hoping that there is some basic string function which will do this that I just haven't found yet.

Specifically for scenarios where length of the string is unknown:
Is there a succinct method of telling if a string variable only contains [0-9] values?

For example, the following method works but require additional mention of all possible characters that would appear other than numerals.

```
SELECT VAR 
FROM #TABLE1 
WHERE VAR NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

and

```
SELECT VAR 
FROM #TABLE1 
WHERE VAR LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]...'
```

doesn't work because the length of the VAR is required for this filter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, you want to select all results from a column only when the value is numeric?  Maybe post a sample table with the expected results of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT VAR FROM #TABLE1 
WHERE VAR NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```